# How to minimize expressions of the form $|Ax+By+C|$ with $x$ and $y$ integers and $A,B,C \in \mathbb R$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, linear-programming

pretty straight forward question, I know how to do it if $A,B \in \mathbb Z$ (I believe it is the $\frac{C}{\gcd(A,B)}$).

But what if $A,B$ and $C$ are just given real numbers with no gcd?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but x=y=0 is the minimum

Comment: Maybe it was a bad question

Comment: $\frac C{\gcd(A,B)}$ is not even always an integer, so that doesn’t work when $A,B,C$ are integers.

Comment: @trula no. Might be true if all values were non-negative, but not in general.

Comment: When $A,B,C$ are integers, it is the minimum value of $(\pm C)\bmod {\gcd(A,B)}.$ For general reals, there might not even a minimum. For example, $A=\sqrt2,b=\sqrt6, C=1.$ The infimum is zero in “most” cases of $(A,B,C).$

Comment: Consider the special case $A\neq 0$, $C=0$ and $y\neq 0$, then the expression we want to minimize is $|Ay|\cdot \left|\frac xy+\frac BA\right|$. Because $|A|$ is fixed, what we are trying to do here, is to approximate the real number $A/B$ by a fraction $x/y$, while keeping the denominator $y$ relatively small. This is a fascinating problem, and its 'answer' can be found in Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem on one hand, and Roth's theorem on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! In order to say something meaningful, I'll consider the simplified problem where $C=0$. That is, given $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, find integers $x,y$ with $|Ax+By|$ minimal. One problem: This is trivial as we can just take $x=y=0$. So let's impose an additional restriction: $y$ can't be zero. Moreover, if $A=0$ we end up with $|By|$ which is minimized by $y=1$. Not very interesting either, so we'll say that $A\neq 0$.

Now we can rewrite the expression we want to minimize as
$$|A|\cdot |y|\cdot\left|\frac xy+\frac BA\right|.$$
Here, the $|A|$ factor isn't very interesting (why?), and $B/A$ is just any real number. We now reformulate the question a little bit:

**Reformulated question:** *Let $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ be any real number. For what $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $y\neq 0$ is
$$
|y|
\cdot \left|\xi-\frac xy\right|
$$
minimal?*

This question has an answer, and it is given by the following famous result.

**Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem:** Let $\xi\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ be an irrational real number, then there exist infinitely many pairs of integers $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $y\neq 0$, $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and
$$
\left|\xi-\frac xy\right|<\frac1{y^2}.
$$
Note that for any such pair, $|y|\cdot\left|\xi-\frac{x}{y}\right|<\frac1{|y|}$, which can be as small as we want it to be! Just pick a pair with $|y|$ large enough. Therefore, the **infimum is zero**. However, for irrational values of $\xi$, there is no pair $(x,y)$ that actually gives zero, so **the minimum doesn't exist**.

---

One can also ask if we can do better than Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem. As it turns out, if $\xi\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is *algebraic*, we cannot:

**Roth's Theorem:** Let $\xi\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ be an irrational algebraic number, then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there are only finitely many pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $y\neq 0$, $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and
$$
\left|\xi-\frac{x}{y}\right|<\frac1{q^{2+\varepsilon}}.
$$

---

**How do you actually find the $(x,y)$ in Dirichlet's theorem?** I don't know, but seeing as a common proof uses Minkowski's first convex body theorem, efficiently finding good $(x,y)$ probably involves use of the LLL-algorithm.